# How do I show data from gravity forms in my template?

Tags: plugins, database, plugin-gravity-forms

## Preface

I've installed gravity forms, created a form and users are submitting data to my site.
What I want to do is show the data users are submitting to my site on one of my pages.

I know there's the [Gravity Forms Directory](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gravity-forms-addons/) plugin.
But this gives only a fixed data presentation.

## Question

**Is there anything in gravity forms that can do something like this? (pseudo code)**:

```
<?php gforms_get_field( $form_id, $entry_id, 'user_name_field' ); ?>
```

Comment: http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Developer_Docs

Comment: @GhostToast Believe me I combed the docs completely and there isn't any information on how to achieve this.

Comment: Note from the future: here's a plugin that is explicitly for displaying Gravity Forms data on the front-end: https://gravityview.co/

Comment: I bet that if I posted this question on SO they would tell me to post it here :-)
Something that has already happened with another question..

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can look at the docs, but you'll probably end up reading the *real* documentation: the source code.

If you do, you'll find that:

- `GFFormsModel::get_leads($form_id)` returns a list of entries for a form (maybe you know that one already), where each item in the array is itself an array, an "[Entry object](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Entry_Object)"
- `GFFormsModel::get_form_meta($form_id)` returns a list of field meta elements (i.e. describes name, type, rules etc.) in the form, where each item in the array is a "[Field object](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Fields)"

Once you have an Entry object, you can access the fields as elements, by field number. If you need to find a field by name or type, you need to iterate over the list of fields in the form to get a match, and then access the entry's field by field ID.

NB: determining a field's type is best done by passing the field's meta element to `GFFormsModel::get_input_type($field)`

Edit: note also that only the first 200 characters of each field are returned in the Entry object. If you have fields that store more information, you'll need to ask for it, e.g. by calling `GFFormsModel::get_field_value_long($lead, $field_number, $form)`.

Comment: FYI, A Gravity Forms admin posted this snippet for a shortcode http://pastebin.com/kHpaHQvi as well.

Answer (score 21):

Thanks to webaware for their answer.

Here's some copy/pasta for anyone looking for a quick start. This takes an entry ID and retrieves the lead and form from that. In this case I'm using the URL to pass the value. e.g. somedomain.com?entry=123.

```
<?php 
    $lead_id = $_GET['entry'];
    $lead = RGFormsModel::get_lead( $lead_id ); 
    $form = GFFormsModel::get_form_meta( $lead['form_id'] ); 

    $values= array();

    foreach( $form['fields'] as $field ) {

        $values[$field['id']] = array(
            'id'    => $field['id'],
            'label' => $field['label'],
            'value' => $lead[ $field['id'] ],
        );
    }
?>
<pre><?php print_r($values); ?></pre>
```

Comment: You code is great but wont work for `Advanced fields` like the `address` or the `first name/last name` since they are using `.` to split their ID

Comment: Also will not work in chckboxes.

Comment: How to get the user info who post the entry?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `gform_after_submission` hook to write everything you need to a custom post type, which might be easier to manipulate "out in the field", and will be safe from, say, someone deleting a single field and obliterating all the data associated with it.

http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_after_submission

Yoast has a pretty good writeup on writing to custom fields, without even using the hook.
http://yoast.com/gravity-forms-custom-post-types/

Good luck!

Comment: Duplicating data like this seems a bit nasty.