# Displaying Gravity Form data on Wordpress page

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-gravity-forms

How can I display the data from within a Gravity Form on a Wordpress page?

(This may be too detailed, but in case anybody wants details about what I'm trying to do, here they are):

I have two Gravity Forms - a pledge form, and a recruit form:

- The recruit form (e.g. www.test.com/recruit) is used to create a referral URL that adds a user-specified code onto the end of the pledge form URL. It also captures the user's email.
- The pledge form (e.g. www.test.com/pledge) is used to capture user information (name, email, etc.), and when a user fills it out with a URL that contains a referral code (e.g. www.test.com/pledge/?referrer=iamthereferralcode), the form also captures that code in a field called "referrer".

I need to display the top 5 referral URLs and their email addresses on a certain page on my Wordpress site.

I'd appreciate any insight. Thank you!

Comment: checkout this thread: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82791/how-do-i-show-data-from-gravity-forms-in-my-template/82916#82916

Comment: Alternately you could create a WordPress custom field to store referrer URLs / emails, populate them via hidden Gravity Form fields. Then on your page retrieve the values of the custom field, do a count, display the top 5.